# Do "Thriller" and "I do like to be beside the seaside" share thematic material?

Tags: analysis

Rod Temperton was born in Cleethorpes, a seaside town on the east coast of the UK.

He also wrote the song Thriller for Michael Jackson.

Bearing these two facts in mind, it struck me there was a similarity between…

- …the two distinctive chords in Thriller, which appear in the intro and also in the chorus:

[image: two bar quote from Thriller]

- …the tune and harmonization of the two words "do like" from the chorus of the song "I do like to be beside the seaside", composed in 1907 by John Glover-Kind:

[image: quote from "I do like to be beside the seaside"]

I known these quotes are in different keys, and neither of these is the definitive harmonization, but I think both tunes could be harmonized as a I chord with the tune descending from the 6th to the 5th degree of the scale. Coincidence?

Comment: Coincidence? Yes.

Comment: No plagiarisation here. Sorry!

Comment: I'm sure I spotted a similar coincidence right at the end of Seven Seas of Rhye… though I could have been mistaken ;)

Answer (score 1):

All the two examples have in common is a melody moving from the 6th to 5th degree.   In 'Thriller' they are harmonised with two different chords, vi and I.   In 'Seaside' they are both harmonised by I.

You have a great future as a music industry lawyer!