# melody analysis according to chord or structural tones?

Tags: analysis, melody

I have come across two ways of studying melody.
First way is with structural tones(melodic outline) and second way is with chords(chord/none-chord tones).

I assume considering melodic outline is only when chords are not available.
Then, when there are chords present in a lead sheet, considering melodic outline really necessary?

Comment: Chords in a lead sheet are not a harmonic analysis. They're instructions for accompaniment. If there's a chord symbol F and the melody has an E note - if that makes the accompanist play a simple F major triad and a soloist a simple E note, you effectively get an Fmaj7 chord. The whole chord-tone vs non-chord-tone question is subjective and genre dependent. An acquired taste.

Comment: This may not fully answer your question, but I suggest reading it and then updating your question based on what you learn: [Can two songs share the same melodic notes but still have distinct melodies?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/132443/70803).

Answer (score 0):

Theory on melody is not as well covered, and easily available, as theory about harmony. So, if you want to get into studying melody, take time to build up a good collection of resources.

However, this much should be said about your question: it is not an either or case. Rather that choose analysis by *chord tones* or *structural tones*, as if those are mutually exclusive, you want to use both analysis tools.

When you say "lead sheet" I assume we are taking about melodies in a homophonic style. That is, melodies that could be harmonized with chords. If you are analyzing such a melody and there happens to be no chords given, you can, and probably should in many cases, analyze the melody according to its harmonic implications.

Answer (score 0):

Analyze the melody. Lead sheets are not that good in general. If you get the melody analyzed, you may find more than one possible harmony.

A good (very old but the principles still apply and there is a free pdf) book on melody is Geotschius' "Exercises in Melodic Writing." It's good for most songs. Once you get the basics, you can expand as your ear tells you.